# Quarkus kafka multi-threaded message consumption?

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, microprofile

How to make multi-thread message listener for quarkus with microprofile reactive messaging system ?

Comment: AFAIK, it's already multiple threads

Comment: What makes you think it isn't? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0 it works only one thread. Am i wrong ? INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.KafkaConsumer] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=quarkus-kafka-example]

Comment: Do you have any solution on how to increase the thread or consumers within the same consumer group.